# In a loop, is it more efficient to set a state value every time or to check to see if it has changed and then set it?

Tags: performance, getter-setter

I'm in a situation where I'm iterating through a number of records and setting state information based on the data in those record. Something like this (not real code, just a simplification):

```
StateObject state;
ConcurrentQueue<Record> records;

while(!records.IsEmpty()) 
{
  //set state here based on the next record
}
```

So, would it be more efficient/better practice to

```
{
  //set state here based on the next record
  Record r = records.next();
  state = r.state;
}
```

or

```
{
  //set state here based on the next record
  Record r = records.next();
  if(state != r.state)
    state = r.state;
}
```

Comment: That's easy to find out - try it.

Comment: is setting the state really a bottleneck? Did you verify this using a profiler? I think setting the state compared to retrieving the next record is negligible.

Answer (score 2):

it's totally depends on your type of records. in some case 1st is better and in some case 2nd one is better.

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself, this is a simplification.  The actual answer depends on the specifics of your situation: you could be running to a database on the other side of the world, in which case an update might be prohibitively expensive.  Alternatively, your state variable could be a massively complex type that is expensive to compare.

As @harold said in his comment: "try it."  Profile your code and gain some understanding of what's expensive and what's not.  Chances are the results will not be what you expect!

Answer (score 0):

Testing is expensive, I simplified your code to this:

```
int x = 5;

if (x == 5)
    x = 4;

x = 4;
```

Here is the disassembled code:

```
                int x = 5;
00000036  mov         dword ptr [rsp+20h],5 

            if (x == 5)
0000003e  xor         eax,eax 
00000040  cmp         dword ptr [rsp+20h],5 
00000045  setne       al   
00000048  mov         dword ptr [rsp+28h],eax 
0000004c  movzx       eax,byte ptr [rsp+28h] 
00000051  mov         byte ptr [rsp+24h],al 
00000055  movzx       eax,byte ptr [rsp+24h] 
0000005a  test        eax,eax 
0000005c  jne         0000000000000066 
                x = 4;
0000005e  mov         dword ptr [rsp+20h],4 

            x = 4;
00000066  mov         dword ptr [rsp+20h],4
```

That being said, premature optimization is a waste of time.  A database call may take one second, the above call may take .00000001 second.

Write the code that is simplest, optimize it later.

Comment: That assembly was obviously generated without optimization, so I don't think that actually counts.

Comment: What is obvious?   Try it in Release and Debug modes, it counts.  And don't confuse IL with the generated assembly code.

Comment: IL? You did this in C#? Not surprising it looks like this then, just uncheck the box that says "Suppress JIT optimization on module load" and look at the real code. My point is, of course it's expensive *in debug code*. That doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: Exactly. So that doesn't really do too much to support that "testing is expensive" (which it is, but for branch misprediction reasons)

Comment: Right, debug or release doesn't matter.  In either case, testing is more expensive than a simple assignment.